# HTAccess Multiple Pages

Tags: .htaccess

I need to convert this

www.test.com/app.program?id=5

into

www.test.com/app.program/5

I already have it setup to remove the .php file extension I just need a something dynamic to whatever app.program is and whatever the id is.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ /$1?id=$2 [L]
```

Change `[L]` to `[L,QSA]` if you want query strings to be appended to the end, for example if you try to access: `http://www.test.com/app.program/5?some-other-param=value`, it'll be appended to the end of the rewrite so that the URI is: `/app.program?id=5&some-other-param=value`

Comment: What is app.program is dynamic like it could be app1.program2 or app2.program1 etc?